# Sending Outlook HTML email using Excel VBA generates runtime error

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send a message from Excel. It triggers a run time error when I get to `.HTMLBody`.

```vb
Sub CreateHTMLMail()
  
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
    With xMailOut
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
        .Display
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Strange, i copied your code and it did work. Outlook showed up the mail with the expected html-Body. (MS Office 365 64-bit)

Comment: Are you able to switch Formats manually? Some software policy can lock down HTML format emails to Plain Text only.

Comment: When I manually edit a message, I can switch format.  My default format is HTML.

Comment: my version is  32 bits, does it change anything ?

Comment: Try - xOutApp = New Outlook.Application

Comment: no success with this command